# HDFS balancer iterations are all idle

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

On my 3-machine cluster, Hadoop version 2.7.3, data-node utilization has become pretty unbalanced, so I am trying to use `hdfs balancer` to fix the problem. But the balancer *does nothing*. Every single iteration goes like this (note that I have hidden the actual IP addresses of the nodes):

> Aug 28, 2017 12:12:50 PM          8                  0 B           289.99 GB              10 GB
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/[Datanode1Addr]:50010
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/[Datanode2Addr]:50010
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /default-rack/[Datanode3Addr]:50010
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO balancer.Balancer: 2 over-utilized: [[Datanode1Addr]:50010:DISK, [Datanode3Addr]:50010:DISK]
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO balancer.Balancer: 1 underutilized: [[Datanode2Addr]:50010:DISK]
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO balancer.Balancer: Need to move 289.99 GB to make the cluster balanced.
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO balancer.Balancer: Decided to move 10 GB bytes from [Datanode1Addr]:50010:DISK to [Datanode2Addr]:50010:DISK
>
> 17/08/28 12:12:59 INFO balancer.Balancer: Will move 10 GB in this iteration

...with no data ever getting moved.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your replication factor set to?

Comment: It's set to 3:
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a replication factor of 3 and only 3 nodes in your cluster, then the HDFS Balancer cannot migrate data since you have to maintain 3 copies of the data and HDFS does not replicate data on the same node.

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense, and I've changed the replication factor to 2 with positive results